# Question about the definition of the dot (inner) product

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, the dot product is defined on $V \times V \to F$ where $V$ is a vector space and $F$ is the field. In other words, the dot product is taken between two vectors.

Let $V^*$ be the dual of $V$. Physicists often define the dot product on $V \times V^* \to 
F$, that is, a dot product is taken between a vector and a covector.

This discrepancy is troubling to me. How is it possible to reconcile the two definitions of the dot product?

Comment: If $V$ is a Hilbert space then $V$ is isometrically isomorphic to $V^*$ by Riesz' representation theorem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem). I can't elaborate on this any further though since I don't know exactly how and where they use this definition. But this might explain the discrepancy to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

By Riesz representation theorem, there's an isomorphism between a Hilbert space and the space of continuous linear functions on that space.

Comment: But what about finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @user125226 finite dimensional vector spaces are, in particular, hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that since in physics we usually associate Hilbert spaces with infinite dimensional spaces in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no discrepancy because these two definitions of the dot product mapping

$a: V \times V \rightarrow F$
$b: V \times V^* \rightarrow F$

are interchangeable by the rule
$b(v, w) = a(v, w^T)$

So if you apply $a$ to two column vectors $v$ and $w$ you will get the same result as if you apply $b$ to a column vector $v$ and the line vector corresponding to $w$.